# move uv coordinate when moving vertex

Tags: uv

Is it possible to move a vertex, and have that vertex also be moved on the UV mp as well?
I'm trying to improve the boundaries of a modeled leaf:

[image]

And it is a pain to fist move the vertex and then correct the UV map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be looking for the *Correct Face Attributes* option:

[image]

[image]